# Copy current value of System.IterationPath in TFS Work Item workflow

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Is it possible to set a custom field to a copy of the current value of System.IterationPath in a transition of a TFS work item workflow?

The problem I've encountered is that using a COPY doesn't appear to work as it complains that you can't copy from a TreePath to a String field (and you can't make a custom field of type TreePath).

eg. This doesn't work

```
<CopyRule from="field" field="System.IterationPath" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Most rules are disabled on the special fields like Area and Iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will help you but you can use System.IterationId field (which is an integer) in the copy rule.

Comment: I suspect you might be right. I assume that in that case the only way to view this 'nicely' would be in custom reports, as I'm not aware of a way of doing a 'lookup' from the IterationId back to the Iteration Name

Comment: You can get IterationPath from IterationId using TFS object model:

`WorkItemStore store;
Project p = store.Projects[<project name>];
Node n = p.FindNodeInSubTree(<IterationId>);`

Node object has Path and Name properties.

Or you can look up Iteration name and path from the TFS database by selecting from the xxTree table:

`select [Node Name], [Iteration Path] from xxTree where ID = <Iteration Id>`